# visual studio code menu bar not visible in ubuntu18.10

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I install visual studio code on ubuntu18.10 it's menu bar is not visible. what may be the problem and how can I make it visible?

Comment: Press F11 twice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in `settings.json` add this:

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
```

cheers

Comment: You can also do it in the UI with: `Ctrl-,` and select settings, search for `titlebar` and you can select `custom` there as well.

Comment: where is `settings.json`

Comment: @WestHamster File-> Preferences -> Settings   then search for "titlebar" and set it to custom.  If you want to edit the file directly on linux the file is located at: Linux $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Answer (score 2):

To restore the menu bar press <kbd>F1</kbd> in VSCode and trigger the `View: Toggle Menu Bar` command in the command palette. (Simple start typing **toggle menu** .. after pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you will see `View: Toggle Menu Bar`.)

[image: VS Code]

Then you will see Windows 10 top menu like:

[image: File top menu VSCode like Win 10]

Answer (score 2):

My menus were still there, but can not be seen since the text and background colors were the same. alt + f for instance shows the File menu fine.

To make these menus visible again I had to install gnome tweaks and under **Apprearance > Themes > Applications** choose Yaru-dark.